# MySQL Dump File is Excluding almost all Insert Statements

Tags: java, mysql

I created a DB using MySQL, the script to create this database creates 4 tables and has multiple inserts satetments for each table.

After I run the script the tables are created and the insert statements run without an error.

I run a Java app that also uses the DB and the app runs perfectly and I can see that the insert statements have been added.

However when I create a dump file via the Windows CMD line the sql file that is generated by the CMD Command only contains one insert statement for 
each table. Why does this happen ?

Comment: And is the script correct? You can insert multiple rows with a single insert statement you know. I doubt MySQL is wrong here.

Comment: Ok so you are saying that the script generated by the dump file is probable correct and is adding all of the insert statements through one line, the only problem is that the insert statements are all unique and not copies of each other.

Comment: Well if you haven't even tested the script, you shouldn't be coming here claiming that it's wrong.

Comment: Ok yes you were right,  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use a bulk insert that inserts all rows from one table in one statement (multiple value lists will appear after the insert statement). Depending on how large your tables are, or how many indexes and foreign keys you have, this can be very efficient when dumping and restoring.

I expect that the windows cmd line is invoking this option (--extended-insert or -e) by default, whereas whatever you used to create the initial dump was using single row inserts.

Can you check the output from the windows cmd line dump carefully, or perhaps paste an excerpt from it here?

Alternatively if you just run

```
 mysqldump your-database-name > your-dumpfile-name.sql
```

(ie: no flags or options)

Then you should get multiple insert statements.

Comment: That is exactly what I did run. But I just copied the insert statement and then pasted it else-where and all my insert statements appeared individually so yo guys are right and it must have compressed it.